# fresh installed ubuntu 17.10 on VMware and there is no swap partition

Tags: partitioning, swap

I have recently installed Ubuntu 17.10 Desktop on VMWare workstation with all defaults (including updates and third party software), after installation i checked and there is no swap space/partition, it is required to install Oracle Database 11g. there is only 1 partition of all 60GB, how i can create it and reduce the size of existing / partition? please help. i used **sudo lsblk -o NAME,LABEL** to check. EDIT: sorry i found it with command **sudo swapon --show** but it has 2GB only, how i can increase the size?

Comment: This is the new default. The swap is now a file.

Answer (score 0):

i have found link below to create a file to increase swap space as per my need.
[Link to solution](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-16-04)

regards to all, love to all.